# Storm Spout ERROR backtype.storm.util - Async loop died

Tags: java, apache-storm

My data comes from a sensor that is connected to my storm cluster by a websocket, so whenever a datapoint arrives on my websocket server I add it to a **ConcurrentLinkedQueue**. I have no a priori information regarding the frequency of datapoints "production".
My spout takes the datapoint on this queue and emits the corresponding Tupple. Everythink works well for a while (approximately 1000 datapoints I would say) but then I got the following error:

```
76245 [Thread-23-incDp] ERROR backtype.storm.util - Async loop died!
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at streams.storm.spout.MySpout.nextTuple(MySpout.java:56) ~[bin/:na]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3373$fn__3388$fn__3417.invoke(executor.clj:565) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__464.invoke(util.clj:463) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_67]
76246 [Thread-23-incDp] ERROR backtype.storm.daemon.executor - 
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at streams.storm.spout.MySpout.nextTuple(MySpout.java:56) ~[bin/:na]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3373$fn__3388$fn__3417.invoke(executor.clj:565) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__464.invoke(util.clj:463) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_67]
76481 [Thread-23-incDp] ERROR backtype.storm.util - Halting process: ("Worker died")
java.lang.RuntimeException: ("Worker died")
    at backtype.storm.util$exit_process_BANG_.doInvoke(util.clj:325) [storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:423) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$fn__3808$fn__3809.invoke(worker.clj:452) [storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_executor_data$fn__3274$fn__3275.invoke(executor.clj:240) [storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__464.invoke(util.clj:473) [storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_67]
```

Here is the my spout code:

```
public class MySpout extends BaseRichSpout
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private AtomicLong messageIdCounter = new AtomicLong();     
    private static Queue<String> incData;
    private SpoutOutputCollector collector; 


    public MySpout() 
    {
        incData = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String>();
    }


    @Override
    public void nextTuple() 
    {
        if(incData.isEmpty())
        {
            Utils.sleep(500);
        }
        else
        {
            String[] splittedMsg = incData.poll().split(" ; ");
            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

            try 
            {
                int ts = Integer.parseInt(splittedMsg[0]);
                JSONObject json = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(splittedMsg[1]);
                collector.emit(new Values( ts, new DataPoint(ts, new ArrayList(json.values()))), messageIdCounter.incrementAndGet() );
            } 
            catch (ParseException e) 
            {
                System.err.println("Wrong input format: should be json");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void open(Map conf, TopologyContext context, SpoutOutputCollector collector) {
        this.collector = collector;
    }

    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        declarer.declare(new Fields("time", "dps" ));
    }

    public static void addElmtToQueue(String json)
    {
        incData.add(json);
    }
```

I guess it comes from that something is going wrong with the queue either not anymore datapoints or a concurrent problem between my two thread (by the way I know that making it static could be bad but I've not found another solution since I need to access it on my server thread...). 
Has someone faced the same problem ? Any solutions/comment would be welcomed :)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 56 of MySpout.java is throwing a NullPointerException.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at streams.storm.spout.MySpout.nextTuple(MySpout.java:56) ~[bin/:na]
```

I would wager this line is the problem:

```
String[] splittedMsg = incData.poll().split(" ; ");
```

Due to the fact [that poll() will return null when your queue is empty](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html).

The NullPointerException is causing your spout to crash. I would suggest two things:

1. Check the result of poll() for null and sleep if it is null
2. Wrap your spout in a try/catch to prevent it from killing your topology

Example:

```
@Override
public void nextTuple() {
    try {
        String message = _queue.poll();
        if (message == null) {
            // didn't get a message, sleep for a little bit
            Utils.sleep(50);
        } else {
            // do stuff with message
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        _collector.reportError(e);
        LOG.error("Spout error {}", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you very much it seems to work !! I should have thought about it, but I was pretty sure that `if(incData.isEmpty())` prevented me from this misbehavior !!